# Is there a way to store date and time info in a field in QGIS?

Tags: python-2.7, gis, gdal, qgis, ogr

I have a bunch of input values in this format:

```
2014-05-14 17:42:18
```

And I would like to store them in a field in QGIS.  I am using the Python API for GDAL/OGR.  I notice that QGIS supports a field type "QDate", but it seems that it can only handle dates with no time, as such:

2014-05-14

I'm just wondering if there is a way to get around this or am I stuck storing the timestamp as a string?

Comment: When you say you to store datetime in field. It 's in a field of what ? A layer? Postgis? shape? ... Could you please be more precise. And wich version of Qgis? 1.8 or 2.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the python OGR API has a way to define a datetime field and store data in it (its defined in the [`OFRFieldType` enum](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716130203/http://www.gdal.org:80/ogr__core_8h.html#a787194bea637faf12d61643124a7c9fc). You have to use the `OFTDateTime` (or `OFTDate` or `OFTTime`) type defined by OGR.

So you can do something like :

```
date_field = ogr.FieldDefn("date", ogr.OFTDateTime)
your_layer.CreateField(date_field)
```

then you can set the value for a feature by passing your date as a string:

```
feature = ogr.Feature(your_layer.GetLayerDefn())
feature.SetField("date", "2014-05-14 17:42:18")
```

The result may depend on your output data structure (if it defines/supports a date time type) and on the desktop GIS software you are using to display them.

EDIT : **But** I tested to write a shapefile like this, then open it in QGIS; the *date* field was properly recognized as a `QDate` field, and as you say the time is not showing so I looked in the `.dbf` file and the *time* part doesn't seems to have been written.